# Toggle and counting queries in a large matrix

Tags: algorithm

Given a matrix of 10^18 × 10^18. Every cell is either 0 or 1. Initially all are 0.

Now we need to perform Q queries. We have queries of two types:

**1 x l r**: If `x = 0`, then it means that we should toggle the values of all cells in rows l, l+1, ..., r . 
Otherwise `(x = 1)` we should do this to columns number l, l+1, ... r.

**2 l r x y**: We need to print the number of cells marked 1 in sub rectangle of this matrix, consisting of rows number l, l+1, ..., r and columns number x, x+1, ..., y.

Now if the size of matrix was small, this could have been done. But how to do this for 10^18 size matrix ? We can not create the matrix, we need some algorithm to store these values in efficient way to answer all queries.

Queries count can be up to 100 000. How can I do this efficiently?

Comment: what environment are you planning to use? CUDA?

Comment: @Dinal24 I am coding in C++ only

Answer (score 1):

For each cell, you could calculate its value from knowing the number of times its column has been toggled and the number of times its row has been toggled. Actually you only need to know whether the sum of those two is even or odd, and for that it is enough to know whether each of them individually is even or odd. That is not enough, 2E18 bits is still far too much, but we can use interval trees - the nature of the queries makes that a good fit, and it can 1 bit per element easily as "present / non-present".

So keep two interval trees, one to keep track of which rows have been toggled an odd number of times and one to keep track of which columns have been toggled an odd number of times.

The second query is a bit trickier, in some way it resembled the multiplication of two interval trees, resulting in a "rectangle tree", but you never have to build it explicitly. Pretend the trees are already bounded to the ranges of the query (you can do this implicitly). For each present range in one tree and each *non-present* range in the other tree add the area of the rectangle they make to the total number of 1's. Then do the same thing with the trees swapped.

Here's a visualization, the black ranges represent the contents of the interval trees, the red rectangles represent the implicit contents of the matrix. The algorithm above visits every red rectangle and adds the areas.

[image: matrix]

Comment: Can you add some pseudocode kind of thing ? Assuming I am having standard interval trees :)

Comment: @mat7 maybe but do you need it? Query 1 is just a symmetric difference and query 2 only relies on the enumeration of ranges. That's both standard.